# Reopening database after onpause

Tags: android, database, onresume

I am new to android programming and am just starting to dabble in using a sqlite database. In my app, I am closing the database at onpause and ondestroy.

However, when using the app, I am attempting to reopen the database/app after closing it for a short while, but kept having an error 'unable to open an already closed database'?

Please help. Here is the excerpt of the java file;

```
public class Apple extends Activity {

DbA myDb;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apple_layout);
    openDB();
    }

  private void openDB() {
myDb= new DbA(this);
myDb.open();
}

  @Override 
  protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();  
myDb.close();
  }


  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
myDb.open();
 }

  @Override
 protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();        
myDb.close();   
  }
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post code for "DbA" class you are using too please.

Comment: You don't need to open the database when resuming or when pausing. Open and close it only before and after you use the database.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinions there's no need to keep an open database connection the whole lifecycle of the activity.

I usually get writable database when I'm going to perform an action and close when it finish.

For example, to add records, you can have the following method

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }

    // get writable database and begin transaction
    final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    database.beginTransaction();

    // INSERT ITEM IN DATABASE

    // End transaction and close connection
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    database.close();
}
```